# Консультация кардиологом или кардиолога?

Tags: грамматика, лексическая-сочетаемость, выбор-варианта

Вам нужна консультация кардиолога. Или кардиологом?

Comment: Вы, простите, еду готовить поваром не пробовали? Или ботинки чинить сапожником? Так за что вы так уважаемого врача не любите?

Answer (score 2):

Из словаря сочетаемости слов (стр. 234—235):
[**консультация**](http://vassilenkoanatole.narod.ru/slovar-sochet_slov.pdf)
**1.** Совет специалиста по какому-либо вопросу, а также беседа со
специалистом, имеющая целью получение такого совета.

Консультация **кого**: (о специалисте) ~ врача, юриста, профессора, специалиста... Консультация **по чему**: ~ по какому-либо вопросу, по какому-либо делу...
Консультация **с кем**: ~ с врачом, с юристом, с профессором, со специалистом...
*В этом деле необходима **консультация** опытного **юриста**. Это лекарство очень сильное, его можно принимать только после **консультации с врачом.***

Правильно так (выбор падежа зависит от контекста):
**Вам нужна консультация** [кого? Р. п.] **кардиолога?**
**Вам нужна консультация** [с кем? Т. п.] **с кардиологом?**

*Карташов должен был как-то объяснить Косарю, зачем ему нужна консультация психиатра* (А. Маринина. Украденный сон).
*Кроме того, в законе указано на невозможность ограничивать по времени консультации с адвокатом...*